# @font face css rule is being ignored on my website across all browsers. Please help me

Tags: html, css, fonts

Basically I have been tearing my hair out over this one. I have tried everything I can find on the web and can not get any custom font to work on my site. I'm not a web designer and would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. The following code is what I have in my css file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "digitica";
src: url("digitica.eot");
url("digitica.woff") format("woff");
url("digitica.otf") format("opentype");
url("digitica.ttf") format("truetype");
url("digitica.svg#webfont") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I have all the font types uploaded to the server and am referring to the font as follows:

```
.xyz {
font-family: "digitica"; <<<< Does the space matter between : & "digitica"?
}
```

Then placing:

```
<div class="xyz">
```

around the text I want in this custom font

```
<!-- end .xyz --></div>
```

Please help!

Comment: If it's being ignored across all browsers, then I'd check to see if you're locating the files or not.  I bet this is a path related issue, use Firebug or Chrome Inspector to see if the files are being located.

Answer (score 2):

```
src: url("digitica.eot"),
url("digitica.woff") format("woff"),
url("digitica.otf") format("opentype"),
url("digitica.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("digitica.svg#webfont") format("svg");
```

Use commas not semicolons to separate fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@font-face` syntax is wrong. Try:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'digitica';
    src: url('digitica.eot');
    src: url('digitica.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('digitica.woff') format('woff'),
         url('digitica.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('digitica.svg#digitica') format('svg');
    }

.xyz {
    font-family: "digitica";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dude it solved the problem! So relieved. I have one final question with the >>> .eot?#iefix <<< Do you rename the eot file to that. What is its purpose?

Comment: From http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax (note that the syntax in this blog entry was revised again, which I provided as my answer): "Internet Explorer <9 has a bug in the parser for the src attribute. If you include more than one font format in the src, IE fails to load it and reports a 404 error. The reason is that IE attempts to load as a file everything between the opening parenthesis all the way to the very last closing parenthesis... The question mark fools IE into thinking the rest of the string is a query string and loads just the EOT file."